# Image src have extra number on heroku but it works locally why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, heroku

The Image are shown locally but its cant shown on heroku why?

When i open inspect element it have numbers after the src image like this

```
<img alt="" src="/assets/slider-1-small-5becce2e5e78cb63c4cdb619548f388c.jpg">
```

Comment: The number is a ***fingerprint*** added when you ***precompile*** the assets.

Answer (score 2):

The number that you see in the image name is the fingerprinting, that Rails adds to assets in production environment, to assure, that if you update some asset, it will not be loaded from a browser cache for a user, who already visited your website.

You can read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

But i suppose, that the problem that you have, might be related with a config `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your `config/production.rb` file. Heroku has a nice article about the Rails 4 deployment and Assets Pipeline in general:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: Its still not working I add change this line from false to true on production.rb

Comment: have you followed this guide? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: maybe there is something else you missed

Comment: I have no idea what ,There some image can show but other have the extra numbers

Comment: Are the images, that are shown, stored in the public folder of your project?